# Missing tag - network switch

Tags: discussion, tags

It was when I was changing the tag of this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271626/know-the-switch-interface-from-the-host-ip-adress

that I came to know that there isn't a tag for a "network-switch" on stackoverflow. My question is don't we need one? If so, please do create one.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: They probably have that tag already on sites that deal with networking issues, like [SU] and [SF]. We don't have one Stack Overflow, because that question is off-topic there. We deal only with *programming* questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a tag is really needed, a user with enough reputation will tag a post (maybe their own) with it and it will be created.

You can't just request a tag creation - the only way for it to exist is to have a post tagged with it.

The tag probably won't be created if there is no use for it. If you explain why you think it should be created, then a user with enough reputation might do it for you. (You should add a comment on your question stating this if you have a good reason.)